# A simple problem on limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove that  for all $x,a\in R^+$ and for all $n\in R$,
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow a}x^n=a^n
$$
I have no idea how to prove it, and I am a beginner in calculus, so I have asked this simple problem. Please, give me a formal and detailed solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a problem for a beginner. The definition itself of $x^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x>0$ is complicated.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the fact that $$x^n=e^{n\ln x}$$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^+$ and all $n\in\Bbb R.$ What do you know about limits and continuous functions?

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary continuous at $x=a$  function $f(x)$  holds 
$$
\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=f(a).
$$

The function $x^n$  is continuous at $x=a.$ Thus 
$$
\lim_{x \to a}x^n=a^n.
$$